# C# Removing data from a list

Tags: c#, list

So I have recently started working with C# and now I got a project to do at home...

I have a situation where I have a data file with information about an undefined amount of rings.... Their Maker, Name, Metal, Weight, Size, Purity and Price.

I've read the file... and separated the rings into a class which looks like:

```
class Rings
    {
        public string Maker { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Metal { set; get; }
        public string Weight { set; get; }
        public string Size { set; get; }
        public string Purity { set; get; }
        public string Price { set; get; }

        public Rings() { }
        public Rings(string maker, string name, string metal, string weight, string size, string purity, string price)
        {
            Maker = maker;
            Name = name;
            Metal = metal;
            Weight = weight;
            Size = size;
            Purity = purity;
            Price = price;
        }
    }
```

Now the final part of the project is to find and print to a file rings, which are under 300 in price and are either size 13 or 14... So I came up with the idea to make a loop and a couple of if functions to delete all rings which do not suit these requirements from the list, and then simply print out what's left of the list...
Here's the method:

```
public static void SpecificRings(List<Rings> RingList)
        {

            foreach(var x in RingList)
            {
                int ThePrice = int.Parse(x.Price);
                int TheSize = int.Parse(x.Size);
                if (ThePrice >= 300)
                {
                    RingList.Remove(x);
                }
                else if (TheSize != 12 || TheSize != 13)
                {
                    RingList.Remove(x);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the problem is that I do not know how to remove the actual things from the list... I understand that I'll need to make 7 of the RingList.Remove(); But how do I specify which information to delete? Any questions are welcome if I didn't explain the situation well enough

Comment: What is wrong with the current code?

Comment: The problem is the thing inside RingList.Remove(**HERE**);.... I need to specify the 7 types of data about each ring that I want to remove

Comment: Try `RingList.Remove((Rings)x);`

Comment: Why don't you make the price and size in the class integers instead of strings?

Comment: @BligenN Whuh? I would expect the problem to be that you're altering the list while enumerating it in the foreach.

Comment: @juharr I'd make price a decimal, myself. Pbthbththb.

Comment: @EdPlunkett that is a good point. Probably better if you change it to a for loop and get objects one by one based on index.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeah I'm gonna need to know what that last part means (acronym?)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I was just going off the conversion to `int`.  But yeah if the price can have a decimal place in it then that would be better.

Comment: What you *really* want to do here is leave Br...`RingList` alone, and make a new list including the ones you want: `var affordableRings = RingList.Where(r => r.Price < 300 && (r.Size == 12 || r.Size == 13)).ToList();` You can grab all kinds of subsets that way, without disturbing your original collection.

Comment: @mmcrae That was onomatopoeia. It can be disregarded.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That seems like the most practical way as I'm VERY fresh to c#... and I'm not even studying it in english but in my native language making it hardly possible to understand what people are even trying to suggest, how do I do the new list?

Comment: `List<Rings> CorrectRings = RingList.Where(r => r.Price < 300 && (r.Size == 12 || r.Size == 13)).ToList();` like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to run into trouble here. Just to start with, you can't remove an item from a collection while you're enumerating the collection in a `foreach` loop.

```
        foreach(var x in RingList)
        {
            int ThePrice = int.Parse(x.Price);
            int TheSize = int.Parse(x.Size);
            if (ThePrice >= 300)
            {
//  >>> Exception will be throw on next line
                RingList.Remove(x);
```

The second proplem is that you've got one list of Rings, and you're removing items from it. Then they're gone. That can cause confusion.

There's a third problem:

```
if (TheSize != 12 || TheSize != 13)
```

That's not going to work well. Every ring is either not size 12, *or* not size 13. If it's 13, it's not 12; if it's 12, it's not 13. That line will discard everything.

I *think* you mean you want to keep *only* size 12 and size 13 rings, but that's a guess. Maybe you want to *discard* only size 12 and size 13? Let me know.

Here's a very simplified version of the function I would write to do what you're doing in `SpecificRings`. You say you're at a very early stage of learning, so I'll try to stick with stuff you've probably seen already.

First, if a function is getting specific rings, call it `GetSpecificRings()`. The compiler doesn't care, but it makes it easier to keep track of what your code is doing in your own mind.

But first, let's not use strings for everything:

```
class Rings
{
    public string Maker { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Metal { set; get; }
//  All these should be numbers
    public decimal Weight { set; get; }
    public decimal Size { set; get; }
    public decimal Purity { set; get; }
    public decimal Price { set; get; }
```

And now to get our specific rings:

```
public List<Rings> GetSpecificRings(List<Rings> rings)
{
    var rtn = new List<Rings>();

    foreach (var r in rings)
    {
        if (r.Price < 300 && (r.Size == 12 || r.Size == 13))
        {
            rtn.Add(r);
        }
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

Then you can call that function to get that subset of rings:

```
var myAffordableRingsInSomeSizes = GetSpecificRings(RingList);
```

I assume you're getting `RingList` from somewhere, like a database, or just statically initializing it. We can go into that further if we need to.

Here's another way to do the same thing, using stuff you may not have learned yet:

```
var sameResults = RingList.Where(r => 
            r.Price < 300 && (r.Size == 12 || r.Size == 13))
        ).ToList();
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, used the first method you suggested and it worked out :) You're a beautiful person and I love you

Answer (score 1):

First, change the types of properties on Rings to what they actually represent. That way you can do comparisons on the data (say, rings weighing more than 10 grams and worth less than $100).

```
class Rings
{
    public string Maker { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Metal { set; get; }
    public double Weight { set; get; }
    public float Size { set; get; }
    public string Purity { set; get; } //I don't know what this is... An int?
    public decimal Price { set; get; }

    public Rings() { }
    public Rings(string maker, string name, string metal, double weight, float size, string purity, decimal price)
    {
        Maker = maker;
        Name = name;
        Metal = metal;
        Weight = weight;
        Size = size;
        Purity = purity;
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

Secondly, don't remove them from the list. Just return a new list with the rings you're looking for. What if you want to find a specific set of rings, then you decide you want a slightly different filter applied? Don't re-read the list, just re-use it:

```
public static IEnumerable<Rings> FilterRings(IEnumerable<Rings> RingList, decimal price, string maker /* etc.......*/)
{
    return ringList.Where(r => r.Price <= price /* or > or == or whatever*/)
                   .Where(r => r.Maker == maker);
                 //.Where etc.. etc...
}
```

You don't even really need the function above. Just call the Linq method directly with what you're looking for.